# Proving A Trigonometric Identity- Double Angles

Tags: trigonometry

$(\cos(2x)-\sin(2x))(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)) = \cos(4x)$ I'm trying to prove that the left side equals the right side. I'm just stuck on which double angle formula of cosine to use.

Comment: It appears that you have asked several questions and got good answers to them. Since you clearly find the site useful, consider acknowledging the effort that the authors of those answers have put in by upvoting and/or accepting the answers you found useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\cos(2x)-\sin(2x))(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x))=(\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)) = \cos(4x)$$
From
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a\sin b$$ if $a=2x,b=2x$ then
$$\cos(4x)=\cos^22x-\sin^22x$$

Answer (score 1):

$cos(4x) = cos(2(2x)) = cos^2(2x)-sin^2(2x) = (cos(2x)-sin(2x))(cos(2x)+sin(2x))$